# Why do I have to restart my app for my RecyclerView to display data from SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

**EDIT 1**: I used debugging statements and it turns out that when I add an item to the database it is successful. However, the updateUI() method is not called because what I am launching is a DialogFragment() so my ListActivity does not enter a paused state. But, if I exit the app and launch again the adapter gets updated. So now the question becomes how do I update the adapter **after** exiting the dialog fragment?

---

I'm building a simple list app and added SQLite database to store task object. I am successfully adding items to the database, but they do not show up immediately in the RecyclerView I am using to show all tasks. It is only when I completely exit from the app and reload that tasks items show up in the RecyclerView.

ListFragment.java this will create the RecyclerView

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String DEBUG_LOG = "debug_message";
private static final String ADD_DIALOG = "add_dialog";
private static final int REQUEST_TITLE = 0;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private TaskAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.the_task_list);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    updateUI();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == ListFragment.REQUEST_TITLE) {

        UUID taskId = (UUID) data.getSerializableExtra(EditTaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID);
        String newTaskName = data.getStringExtra(EditTaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_TITLE);

        if(newTaskName != null) {
            Task task = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTask(taskId);
            task.setTitle(newTaskName);
            TaskLab.get(getActivity()).updateTask(task);
        }

        updateUI();
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_item, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_new_task:
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            AddTaskFragment dialog = new AddTaskFragment();
            dialog.show(manager, ADD_DIALOG);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}


public void updateUI() {

    // Retrieves ArrayList<Task>
    List<Task> taskList = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTaskList();

    if(mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(taskList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }else {
        mAdapter.setCrimes(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskHolder>{

    private List<Task> mTaskList;

    public TaskAdapter(List<Task> taskList) {

        mTaskList = taskList;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.task_list_layout, parent, false);
        return new TaskHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, int position) {
        final Task currentTask = mTaskList.get(position);
        holder.bindData(currentTask);

        final TextView taskTitle = holder.mTaskTitle;

        holder.mSolved.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
               if(isChecked) {
                   taskTitle.setPaintFlags(taskTitle.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                   currentTask.setSolved(true);
               }else {
                   taskTitle.setPaintFlags(taskTitle.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
               }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTaskList.size();
    }

    public void setCrimes(List<Task> taskList) {
        mTaskList = taskList;
    }
}

private class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Task mTask;
    private TextView mTaskTitle;
    private CheckBox mSolved;

    private static final String EDIT_DIALOG = "edit_dialog";

    public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTaskTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        mSolved = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_solved);
    }

    public void bindData(Task task) {
        mTask = task;
        mTaskTitle.setText(mTask.getTitle());
        mSolved.setChecked(mTask.isSolved());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!mSolved.isChecked()) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            EditTaskFragment dialog = EditTaskFragment.newInstance(mTask.getId());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(ListFragment.this, REQUEST_TITLE);
            dialog.show(manager, EDIT_DIALOG);
        }
    }

}
```

AddTaskFragment.java this will allow the user to add a task item to the RecyclerView

```
public class AddTaskFragment extends DialogFragment {

private EditText mTaskTitle;

private void addTask() {

    if(!mTaskTitle.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setTitle(mTaskTitle.getText().toString());

        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).addTask(task);
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_dialog,null);
    mTaskTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.task_title);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(view)
            .setTitle(R.string.add_new_task_dialog_title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_new_task_dialog_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    addTask();
                }
            })
            .create();
}
}
```

TaskLab.java this is a singleton class

```
public class TaskLab {

private static TaskLab sTaskLab;

private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

private TaskLab(Context context){
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    mDatabase = new TaskBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
}

public static TaskLab get(Context context) {
    if(sTaskLab == null) {
        sTaskLab = new TaskLab(context);
    }

    return sTaskLab;
}


public List<Task> getTaskList(){

    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    TaskCursorWrapper cursor = queryTasks(null, null);

    // If there is something in the table query it
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Task task = cursor.getTask();
            taskList.add(task);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return taskList;
}

public void addTask(Task task) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(task);
    mDatabase.insert(TaskTable.NAME, null, values);
}

public void updateTask(Task task) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(task);
    String uuidString = task.getId().toString();
    mDatabase.update(TaskTable.NAME,values, TaskTable.Cols.UUID + " = ?", new String[] {uuidString});
}

public Task getTask(UUID id){

    TaskCursorWrapper cursor = queryTasks(TaskTable.Cols.UUID + " = ?",
            new String[] {id.toString()});

    try {
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getTask();
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}

private static ContentValues getContentValues(Task task) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(TaskTable.Cols.UUID, task.getId().toString());
    values.put(TaskTable.Cols.TITLE, task.getTitle());
    values.put(TaskTable.Cols.SOLVED, task.isSolved());

    return values;
}

private TaskCursorWrapper queryTasks(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(TaskTable.NAME,
            null,
            whereClause,
            whereArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    return new TaskCursorWrapper(cursor);
}

}
```

Comment: Code too long to follow. One potential issue is the list you are using in your adapter is getting recreated. This list has to be same list and should only be updated in order for notifydatasetchanges to work properly.

Comment: @Jimmy I checked the code and it looks like the list is only getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

It must be reCreate your adapter in updateUI every time from the beginning

Comment: But isn't updateUI() fetching the list from TaskLab? It isn't recreating a new list each time its called.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this and see. In your onCreateView() of fragment before updateUI() add below line of code.

Note: Create taskList as global variable.

```
mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.the_task_list);
mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(taskList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

updateUI();
```

After that create your updateUI() method as below

```
public void updateUI() {
    taskList.clear;
    taskList = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTaskList();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Update:**

As per your updated question, declare one global variable in ListFragment as

```
public static ListFragment listFragment;
```

In your onCreate method of ListFragment after inflating view add below line of code.

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

listFragment = this;
```

Then change your addTask method in AddTaskFragment as below.

```
private void addTask() {
    if(!mTaskTitle.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setTitle(mTaskTitle.getText().toString());

        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).addTask(task);

        //import listfragment from your ListFragment
        listFragment.updateUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it out but it does not work. In fact, when I even reload the app items wont appear in the list.